# Make Attachment File Format only .txt .doc .docx

Tags: php, phpmailer

I create a PHP contact form with file attachment with helping a online tutorial. But i want to function it like user only upload .txt .doc .docx file format, no other format will be accepted.

```
<?php
$from = "name@example.com";
$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject =$_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['body'];

// Temporary paths of selected files
$file1 = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$file2 = $_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'];
$file3 = $_FILES['file3']['tmp_name'];

// File names of selected files
$filename1 = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$filename2 = $_FILES['file2']['name'];
$filename3 = $_FILES['file3']['name'];

// array of filenames to be as attachments
$files = array($file1, $file2, $file3);
$filenames = array($filename1, $filename2, $filename3);

// include the from email in the headers
$headers = "From: $from";

// boundary
$time = md5(time());
$boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$time}x";

// headers used for send attachment with email
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$boundary}\"";

// multipart boundary
$message = "--{$boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
$message .= "--{$boundary}\n";

// attach the attachments to the message
for($x=0; $x<count($files); $x++){
    $file = fopen($files[$x],"r");
    $content = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
    fclose($file);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$filenames[$x]\"\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $content . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$boundary}\n";
}

// sending mail
$sendmail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// verify if mail is sent or not
if ($sendmail) {
    echo "Sent successfully!";
} else {
    echo "Error occurred. Try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to prevent people  from accidentally sending files that wouldn't be helpful or are you trying to prevent malicious users from spreading viruses?

Comment: [See this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1529083/1415724) it will give you a good idea on how to do this. Although I'm not keen on using W3Schools as a reference, [you can see this page](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) under the `Restrictions on Upload` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the use of $_FILE["filename"]["type"] is not recomended for file type checking as the type parameter is browser specific i.e different browser can have different type So we will try to extract the format from the string function

```
$filename=$_FILES["file1"]["name"];//get the name of the file
$extension=strrchr($filename, ".");//extracting the extension

if($extension=".txt" || $extension=".doc" || $extension=".docx")
{
//send mail;
}
else
{
//error;
}
```

Comment: old, but this does not work, nor are the `if` statement operators correct.

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
$filename_array = explode(".",$filename);
$ext = ".".$filename_array[count($filename_array)-1];
if($ext!==".txt" && $ext!==".doc" && $ext!==".docx"):
    //Do bad extension code
endif;
//Do code that passed extension validation
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
$allowed = array('.txt', '.doc', '.docx')
$fileNames = array();

$filename1= $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$ext1 = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(in_array($ext1, $allowed)){
   array_push($fileNames, $filename1);  //repeat for 2, 3, etc...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function allowed_file(){

    //Add the allowed mime-type files to an 'allowed' array 
    $allowed = array('application/doc', 'application/txt', 'another/type');

   //Check uploaded file type is in the above array (therefore valid)  
    if(in_array($_FILES['file']['name'], $allowed))
         {
         // Your code
          }

}
```

Reference : [php file upload, how to restrict file upload type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322137/php-file-upload-how-to-restrict-file-upload-type)

Comment: First, this code would not run. Second, what would it achieve if it did?